# jqgrid form editing hooks

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Ok, so I [RTFM](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) and searched SO and google, and I can't seem to figure out how to add hooks so that I can add a 'loading' icon when a user hits submit when adding/editing a new row from the dialog box in grid. All I need to do is know when the user clicked the submit button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) seems to be what you need.

Comment: I have tried that with no result. Where is it added? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

the form events are attached to the navGrid, not the grid itself:

```
$("#myGrid").navGrid("#commodGrid-pager", {add:false, view:false, del:false,edit:true}
    ,{"onclickSubmit": function(){alert("ouch!");}}, /*edit options*/
    ,{} /*add options*/
    ,{} /*delete options*/
    ,{multipleSearch:false}
    ,{closeOnEscape:true} 
);
```

Comment: Yes of course. The [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) event is the parameter of `editGridRow` function. You can see that from the link to the page documentation which I included. If you use form editing you either call the `editGridRow` function directly (for example in the `ondblClickRow` event of the jqGrid) or configure navigator bar to include "Edit" or "Add" buttons. In the last case you should place `editGridRow` parameters as the parameters of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition).